# google maps and mouse scroll wheel setting

Tags: mac, google-maps, scroll-wheel

Is there a way to change the behavior of the mouse scroll wheel in google maps (in a normal browser window)?

I have a "Mighty Mouse" on my most of my systems, and the logical behavior would be that the built-in trackball provide 360 degree scrolling, not simply increase or decrease the magnification when you scroll up and down.

Comment: Do you mean on the google site? Or do you mean when you use google-maps from OpenLayers for your own maps?

Comment: Is it even possible to read side-scrolling events in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question, but in case someone finds it again...

It seems there was a SafariExtension which disabled scroll for Google Maps but I couldn't find it.

Now I use this javascript bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.addEventListener("mousewheel",function(e){e.stopPropagation()},true)
```

and inject it using dot-js.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [GMouseWheelControl](http://www.pmanslab.com/projects/gmwControl/feature/). I don't know that it will read the side-scrolling (I don't have a mouse with that capability to test with), but it will allow you to pan with the wheel instead of just zoooming in and out.

He says "...I belive Mac computers don't use scroll wheel mouse and as such they will not be able to use this feature.", but I would go ahead and try it anyway - I think his information is a bit out of date.

Comment: Thanks for this info, although this appears to be for web-developers, not for end-users.